# Height Value being read incorrectly in safari (any possible fixes?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a website which is partly being styled with-in jQuery to create sort of an overlapping parallax look. It works perfectly in Chrome and Edge, however when I came to test it in safari it completely messed up. I have managed to nail there issue down to a few JQuery `.height()` values.

This var is checking for the image height within the carousel.

```
var imageSize = $('#myCarousel').height();
```

Using `console.log()` I have worked out that in Chrome is the reading the correct amount however in safari its consoling out 0.

Any help is great

**Live Site** - http://midlandgates.co.uk

**GitHub** - https://github.com/Matthammond96/MidlandGates-Website
(homePageOnload.js & index.html)

Comment: Can you link to a live version of the site?

Comment: If you're only reading in the value, have you tried `document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.height`?

Comment: @Sampson Updated question with a link

Comment: @DrewKennedy I then need to set a few thinks based around its value

Comment: Ahh won't work then. Worth a try!

Comment: @DrewKennedy Yeah I know, it sucks don't get why it isn't working, thanks anyway

Comment: @MattHammond Is the code being ran after all images and styles were loaded and applied?

Comment: use ($(window).on('load', function() {) instead of document ready

Comment: @Sampson yeah, the var is happening as the page is loaded and then later on is setting the values, however as the console logs are say the height = 0 is really confusing me

Comment: @MattHammond What do you get when you call `el.getBoundingClientRect().height` instead, where `el` is your element reference?

Comment: @Tasos on load seemed to work, cheers, do you know why? Browser caching or how the load?

Comment: @Sampson unload seemed to work but thanks for trying :)

Comment: @MattHammond The `load` event fires after media has been loaded, rather than when the DOM has been constructed. As a result, it may take several seconds to execute code in the `onload` handler.

Comment: @Tasos you want to write that as an answer? it worked haha

Comment: @Sampson Ohh that makes sense, so still annoying though haha, as I've been told to use .ready

Comment: @MattHammond In most cases, you should use `DOMContentLoaded` (jQuery's *ready* event). If your code relies on images having been loaded, then you need to wait for those images to load. You may not want to wait for the *entire document* to load, as this could greatly delay your code execution. Usually, you'll want to set container dimensions in CSS to avoid excessive reflows/paints during rendering.

Comment: @Sampson That makes a lot of sense, thank you I shall be sure to remember this when working with images in JQuery Thank you greatly again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the image(s) load first and then get the height

`$(document).ready` function event executes a bit earlier than the load

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

//code

});
```

More info about the difference [here](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/document-ready-vs-window-onload.html)

Comment: Cheers for the simple solution haha

Comment: Just a reminder that this approach will delay your code until *the entire document* has loaded.

Comment: @Sampson -- sure, you can use a container and grab the height of that